# issue with display property of JQuery SelectBoxIt plugin

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I've been trying to use the SelectBoxIt Jquery plugin, but I'm having an issue with the display and disabled properties of dynamically created select boxes. In short, if the original select box has a "display:none" css property, SelectBoxIt still displays it. I went around the issue by inserting the select box in a hidden container div. However, when the container div is displayed, the selectboxit is displayed properly but is now disabled. Do you guys have any clue on how to fix this?

HTML CODE:

```
<div>
<select name="sel" id="sel">
<option value="0">Select this</option>
<option value="1">Select that</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="seladd_xx" style="display:none">
<select name="seladd[]" id="sel_xx">
<option value="0">Select this now</option>
<option value="1">Select that now</option>
</select>
</div>    
<button type="button" id="addbtn_unit" class="addmore" style="font-weight: bold;font-size:11px">Add More</button>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.selectboxit/3.2.0/jquery.selectBoxIt.min.js">        </script>
```

JQUERY CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").selectBoxIt();
    id=0;
    $('.addmore').click(function(){
        newUnit($('#seladd_xx'));
    })

    function newUnit(element) {
        var newElement = element.clone(true);
        if(id <10)id = "0"+id;
        newElement.attr("id",element.attr("id").split("_")[0]+"_"+id);
        $('select', newElement).each(function() {
            var yyid = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[0] + '_' + id;
            $(this).attr('id', yyid);
        });
        $('#seladd_xx').before(newElement);
        newElement.show('fast');
        id++;
    }
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your jQuery selector to not call SelectBoxIt on hidden select boxes.  Like this:

```
$('select:visible').selectBoxIt();
```